# GetDriveType() equivalent in Java

Tags: java, swing, filesystems

Is there any method which performs similar tasks to the GetDriveType() method of Microsoft Visual C++. I've already gone through the FileSystemView class of Java Swing. But the method available there are limited and does not fulfill my requirement.

So please tell me someone if Java defines any such method for Windows platform or Platform Independent.

Comment: `But the method available there are limited and does not fulfill my requirement.` For those of us that don't use Microsoft Visual C++, maybe you should actually state what the GetDriveType() method does and what information you actually require.

Comment: GetDriveType() method returns the TYPE of DRIVE. The declaration is:

int GetDriveType(char*);

It returns the integer value in form of macro as-
{ DRIVE_UNKNOWN, DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR, DRIVE_REMOVABLE, DRIVE_FIXED, DRIVE_REMOTE, DRIVE_CDROM, DRIVE_RAMDISK }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File.listRoots()` method. It will list all the drives in your system.

And to get detail information about that drive you can use the following code.

> List roots = Arrays.asList(File.listRoots()); 
>   for(File f:roots) 
>   { 
>   String s = FileSystemView.getFileSystemview().getSystemTypeDescription(f); 
>   }

This code shows the actual information of drives and other PnP devices. Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) link to know more. And according to your question you must be want to know the hardware details of connected drives to PC. Use JNI if you want to do all code in java.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JDK7?

If so, there is [FileStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#type%28%29) which returns the type as a String.

However, looking at the source code itself ([FileStore.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/FileStore.java)) there is a warning that the return value might be implementation specific.

Comment: Can you explain briefly with an example?